# XPath for elements with same value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml document with a section like this.

```
<MultiplyFunction>
  <Name>HeightModel</Name>
  <LinearInterpolationFunction>
    <Name>WaterStress</Name>
  </LinearInterpolationFunction>
</MultiplyFunction>
<MultiplyFunction>
  <Name>ExtinctionCoeff</Name>
  <LinearInterpolationFunction>
    <Name>WaterStress</Name>
  </LinearInterpolationFunction>
</MultiplyFunction>
```

I want to build an xpath to find the second element `<Name>WaterStress</Name>`. The unique keywords for this element are `ExtinctionCoeff` and `WaterStress`.

My current xpath is `//Name[text()="WaterStress"]` which can find both elements. How should I specify the second one through adding keyword `ExtinctionCoeff`?

Comment: I think `//Name[text()="WaterStress"][2`] would work

Comment: `//MultiplyFunction[Name="ExtinctionCoeff"]/LinearInterpolationFunction/Name[text()="WaterStress"]`

Comment: Thanks for all help. @splash58 your code is working for me. Could you add as an answer, then I can accpet it.

Comment: @Bangyou I've done it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Xpath finds firat MultiplyFunction with name ExtinctionCoeff and then inner LinearInterpolationFunction with bane WaterStress. I split Xpath in 2 line for easy reading

```
//MultiplyFunction[Name="ExtinctionCoeff"]
/LinearInterpolationFunction/Name[tex‌​t()="WaterStress"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work for you...

```
//Name[text()="WaterStress" and ../preceding-sibling::Name='ExtinctionCoeff']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below expression. 
//MultiplyFunction[((descendant::LinearInterpolationFunction/Name[text()="WaterStress"]) and (descendant::Name[text()="ExtinctionCoeff"] ))]

It will return the matching tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options

```html
//MultiplyFunction[2]/LinearInterpolationFunction/Name

//MultiplyFunction[2]//Name[text()="WaterStress"]

//Name[text()="ExtinctionCoeff"]/following-sibling::LinearInterpolationFunction/Name

//Name[text()="ExtinctionCoeff"]/../Name
```